# INSERT INTO MySQL statement failing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am dynamically forming MySQL statements in PHP and can't figure out why this one is failing to execute:

```
    INSERT INTO users ( `email`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `url`,
   `description`, `media`, `tags`, `zip`, `country`, `lat`, `lon`, `city`, `state`, 
   `datetime_joined`, `API_key`, `verified`, `likes`, `email_confirmation_code`,
   `email_confirmed`) VALUES ( 'brannon@brannondorsey.com', 
   'f1e5aeb519396a87bd2a90e6a680d18713b1ecbe', 'Brannon', 'Dorsey',
   'brannondorsey.com', 'description', 'sculpture, photography, creative code',
   'saic, chicago, richmond, young arts', '60601', 'us', '41.8858', '-87.6181',
   'Chicago', 'Illinois', '2013-06-26T23:50:29+0200',
   '7e852a3e97257b563ffbb879d764ce56110ccb70', '0', 
   '0','c35bad0dc9b058addbf47eef8dda2b124528751e', '0')
```

I have checked the spelling and format of the columns that I am tring to insert into as well as the table name and everything is correct. Does anyone know what might be up? I am not trying to make busy work for other people I just can't figure out whats going on here.

Here is the statement that I created my table with:

```
    CREATE TABLE users (
    id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    email varchar(255) default NULL,
    password varchar(255),
    url TEXT default NULL,
    description TEXT default NULL,
    city varchar(255),
    state TEXT default NULL,
    country varchar(100) default NULL,
    zip varchar(10) default NULL,
    datetime_joined varchar(255),
    media varchar(255) default NULL,
    tags varchar(255) default NULL,
    API_key varchar(255),
    verified mediumint default NULL,
    first_name varchar(255) default NULL,
    last_name varchar(255) default NULL,
    API_hits mediumint default NULL,
    API_hit_date varchar(255),
    likes mediumint default NULL,
    lat varchar(30) default NULL,
    lon varchar(30) default NULL,
    email_confirmation_code varchar(255),
    email_confirmed mediumint default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FULLTEXT(`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `url`, `description`, `media`, `tags`, `city`, `state`, `country`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I have tried removing the single quotes from all numbers but that didn't work. Also, most strangely, when I echo the failed query into the browser and then copy & paste it into PhpMyAdmin's sql input box the row inserts... Any ideas?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'brannon@brannondorsey.com\', \'f1e5aeb519396a87bd2a90e6a680d18713b1ecbe\', \'B' at line 1
```

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I copied and pasted the query into PhpMyAdmin and the query row inserted... `1 row inserted. 
Inserted row id: 102 ( Query took 0.0003 sec )`

Comment: That means the code you are using to build the query is stuffing it up, or the query you've posted isn't what it's building. Follow Paul Programmer's advice on getting the actual error, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug through all of the string manipulation I was doing to dynamically build the query and found that I was using `real_escape_string` for a part of the query not just the values going into it. That explains why when copied from the browser the query worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but ur lat and long are inserted as strings, try removing the quotes and insert them as numerals. So with all ur numerical fields.

Comment: Just did but still not executing. I am going to update with my table schema.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your columns and values match up, but unless you show us the statement used to create the table, I can't be sure it fits your schema. It would also be helpful to see the PHP that creates this query. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a mismatch somewhere that we can't see, and you're simply overlooking (can't blame you; it's quite easy to do to your own code).

Other than adding those to bits of code, I have one other possible explanation: Depending on how picky your sql implementation is, maybe it's the missing `;` after your statement.

Comment: I just added a `;` at the end of the query and that didn't work. I will try the rest. I find it really odd however that if I copy and paste the query into phpmyadmin it executes correctly.